# Update a column in PySpark while doing multiple inner joins?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, sql-update, inner-join, azure-databricks

I have a SQL query which I am trying to convert into PySpark. In SQL query, we are joining *three* tables and updating a column where there's a match. The SQL query looks like this:

```sql
UPDATE [DEPARTMENT_DATA]
INNER JOIN ([COLLEGE_DATA]
            INNER JOIN [STUDENT_TABLE]
            ON COLLEGE_DATA.UNIQUEID = STUDENT_TABLE.PROFESSIONALID)
ON DEPARTMENT_DATA.PUBLICID = COLLEGE_DATA.COLLEGEID
SET STUDENT_TABLE.PRIVACY = "PRIVATE"
```

The logic I have tried:

```py
df_STUDENT_TABLE = (
    df_STUDENT_TABLE.alias('a')
    .join(
        df_COLLEGE_DATA('b'),
        on=F.col('a.PROFESSIONALID') == F.col('b.UNIQUEID'),
        how='left',
    )
    .join(
        df_DEPARTMENT_DATA.alias('c'),
        on=F.col('b.COLLEGEID') == F.col('c.PUBLICID'),
        how='left',
    )
    .select(
        *[F.col(f'a.{c}') for c in df_STUDENT_TABLE.columns],
        F.when(
            F.col('b.UNIQUEID').isNotNull() & F.col('c.PUBLICID').isNotNull()
            F.lit('PRIVATE')
        ).alias('PRIVACY')
    )
)
```

This code is adding a new column "PRIVACY", but giving null values after running.

Comment: Can you please edit your question to add a sample data, expected output and the output that you are getting?

Comment: The Expected Output i want if the ON conditions of our joins operator is satisfying we have to update a column PRIVACY in our dataframe with value as 'PRIVATE'.

Comment: PRIVACY Column is already there in our Dataframe and currently Null, we are loading values into the Column by applying joins conditions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- I have taken some sample data and when I apply the join using conditions, the following is the result I get (**requirement is that the following record's privacy needs to be set to `PRIVATE`**)

```
%sql

select student.*,college.*,department.* from department INNER JOIN college INNER JOIN student
ON college.unique_id = student.professional_id and department.public_id = college.college_id
```

[image]

- When I used your code (same logic), I got the same output i.e., an additional column being added to the dataframe with required values and the actual `privacy` column has nulls.

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import col,when,lit

df_s = df_s.alias('a').join(df_c.alias('b'), col('a.professional_id') == col('b.unique_id'),'left').join(df_d.alias('c'), col('b.college_id') == col('c.public_id'),'left').select(*[col(f'a.{c}') for c in df_s.columns],when(col('b.unique_id').isNotNull() & col('c.public_id').isNotNull(), 'PRIVATE').otherwise(col('a.privacy')).alias('req_value'))
df_s.show()
```

[image]

- Since, from the above, `req_value` is the column with required values and these values need to be reflected in `privacy`, you can use the following code directly.

```
final = df_s.withColumn('privacy',col('req_value')).select([column for column in df_s.columns if column!='req_value'])
final.show()
```

[image]

**UPDATE:**

You can also use the following code where I have updated the column using `withColumn` instead of select.

```
df_s = df_s.alias('a').join(df_c.alias('b'), col('a.professional_id') == col('b.unique_id'),'left').join(df_d.alias('c'), col('b.college_id') == col('c.public_id'),'left').withColumn('privacy',when(col('b.unique_id').isNotNull() & col('c.public_id').isNotNull(), 'PRIVATE').otherwise(col('privacy'))).select(*df_s.columns)

#or you can use this as well, without using alias.
#df_s = df_s.join(df_c, df_s['professional_id'] == df_c['unique_id'],'left').join(df_d, df_c['college_id'] == df_d['public_id'],'left').withColumn('privacy',when(df_c['unique_id'].isNotNull() & df_d['public_id'].isNotNull(), 'PRIVATE').otherwise(df_s['privacy'])).select(*df_s.columns)


df_s.show()
```

[image]

Comment: why we are using this Req_value Column, we want data in our Privacy Column

Comment: When we are using alias('PRIVACY') in the code (I used alias('req_column')), it is creating a new column but not updating the `privacy` column. And accessing the column is also ambiguous (since both columns have same name). The values present in the `req_column` are the values that are actual required updated values for privacy column. So, what I have done is that I assigned `req_column` values to `privacy` column and selected only columns present int df_student dataframe initially.

Comment: I have updated the answer where I have directly use `withColumn()` to update the privacy column. Please do check.

Answer (score 1):

After the joins, you can use [**`nvl2`**](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/index.html#nvl2). It can check if the join with the last dataframe (`df_dept`) was successful, if yes, then you can return "PRIVATE", otherwise the value from `df_stud.PRIVACY`.

Inputs:

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
df_stud = spark.createDataFrame([(1, 'x'), (2, 'STAY')], ['PROFESSIONALID', 'PRIVACY'])
df_college = spark.createDataFrame([(1, 1)], ['COLLEGEID', 'UNIQUEID'])
df_dept = spark.createDataFrame([(1,)], ['PUBLICID'])

df_stud.show()
# +--------------+-------+
# |PROFESSIONALID|PRIVACY|
# +--------------+-------+
# |             1|      x|
# |             2|   STAY|
# +--------------+-------+
```

Script:

```py
df = (df_stud.alias('s')
    .join(df_college.alias('c'), F.col('s.PROFESSIONALID') == F.col('c.UNIQUEID'), 'left')
    .join(df_dept.alias('d'), F.col('c.COLLEGEID') == F.col('d.PUBLICID'), 'left')
    .select(
        *[f's.`{c}`' for c in df_stud.columns if c != 'PRIVACY'],
        F.expr("nvl2(d.PUBLICID, 'PRIVATE', s.PRIVACY) PRIVACY")
    )
)
df.show()
# +--------------+-------+
# |PROFESSIONALID|PRIVACY|
# +--------------+-------+
# |             1|PRIVATE|
# |             2|   STAY|
# +--------------+-------+
```